# SSH | скрипт для автонастройки сервера LINUX

Tags: linux, сервер, ssh

Приветствую, написал бота для steam хочу написать скрипт, который будет подключаться по ssh и выполнять такие команды по очередности:

1. Скрипт подключается по ssh и настраивает сервер под linux, такие же команды как мы пишем в консоль для установки, но всё автоматизированно, команда за командой.
2. Устанавливает плагины типа npm.
3. Через npm устанавливает зависимости.
4. Загружает некие файлы на сервер в папку root.

Comment: Пожалуйста, используйте возможности форматирования по назначению. На этом сайте не принято раскрашивать сообщения всеми цветами радуги.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

выполнить несколько команд за одно подключение:

```
$ ssh user@host "команда1; команда2; команда3"
```

скопировать файлы в каталог `/root` на отдалённой машине:

```
$ scp файл1 файл2 файл3 user@host:/root
```

---

эти команды можно поместить в файл и выполнить их:

```
$ bash путь/к/этому/файлу
```

Comment: Нужно только помнить, что точка с запятой между командами - поочерёдное выполнение, не учитывающее результат выполнения прошлой команды. Возможно, автору понадобится выполнять команды только в случае успешного завершения предыдущей. Тогда вместо `;` между командами нужно ставить `&&` (двойной амперсанд). Подробнее - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/command-line-what-is-the-purpose-of

Comment: @user1056837, во-первых, разделителей цепочки команд — [несколько больше двух](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html), во-вторых, по-моему, ru.so — не самое подходящее место для пересказа (даже отдельных глав) документации. // вот появится [раздел для документации](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2786/178576) — там это будет делать гораздо удобнее и практичнее.

Comment: ваш тезис о *пересказе глав документации*  несколько спорный - во всех разделах (и `ru.so` не исключение) достаточно вопросов конкретных, но при этом требующих развёрнутых ответов. В комментарии выше *пересказ* отсутствует, там лишь ссылка на дополнительную информацию, где и приведены ссылки на документацию по `shell`.